# primefaces binding attribute in multiple included pages

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page inc.xhtml included in four different pages. This included page has a component which has binding attribute specified by `binding="#{repeatType}"` Since this page is included in multiple pages my component is not rendering. If i remove the binding attribute it is working. If i am not including it in multiple page, only one page and specifying the binding attribute it is working. I think if i can specify a different binding name for each including page might solve the problem. All the ids in the inc.xhtml are made different by `id="#{idPrefix}_recDrop"`. Id prefix is passed as parameter from the including page. Is there anything that i can do to make the binding name different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the include page to a `composite component`. One of your incoming attributes for the component could then be some bean to bind the component to.

For design reasons it's best to define some interface for the incoming bean which defines the binding attribute. You then can have multiple beans implementing that interface and thus multiple different instances of the `composite component` with another binding instance.